# php, data from table into a specific input inside a html doc

Tags: php, sql, database

I need help getting the last row of a table into a html input tag.
I think an example will help you better understand my question, so here:

```
<input value=<?php $conn->query("SELECT id FROM members ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); ?> , disabled type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" required>
```

I need to put inside the value of the input box, the last id in my "members" table.
thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't show the `id` to the user , why do you want this ?

Comment: its for an administrator panel i build... if the user able to get to this page so he already has enough permissions, so i don't care...

Comment: even if he/she was an administrator giving them the id might end bad on you(for example `id` in most times is `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, giving it to the user to change might ruin that and impact performance)

Comment: leave things like this for DB admins(site admin != DB admin :) )

Comment: i know, that's why the input is disabled, i just want him to view this id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean a bit your code and split it off in two pieces so you can understand that easier if you come back to your code in the future. Something like that:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$userID = "";
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $userID = $row["id"];
}
?>
<input value="<?php echo $userID; ?>" disabled type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" required>
```

If you have just inserted that row you probably want to use [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) instead. I suggest you to read more about that.

Anyway, **print a user id is never a good idea**. Please try to not do that, its a very bad practice.

Comment: mysql_insert_id is deprecated

Comment: Youre right, I just updated the post. Anyway the point here is to understand how it works.

@YoavL I would like to emphasize you shouldnt print a user id even in a hidden or disabled input. Please dont do that.

Comment: Thank's, but guys i don't get why is it a bad idea to print user id, as long as i disable the input and don't let him change it or touch it i guess it's fine. also i wrote to @niceman, that if the user can get to this page it means that he has enough permissions, to at least view things from the database...

Comment: @AndoitzJordán ^?

Comment: I cant see the context of your complete situation but by showing a user id you are exposed to undesired situations.I know your code is probably safe but that information combined with other vulnerabilities like javascript or sql injection are exactly what a hacker might think is a delicious info. Remember ids are usually auto increment and in case I hack your code to inject sql I would test different ids and use your code to confirm my hack is working and then keep going until I have the user I want. As I said, you are probably safe depends of the security of your application.

Comment: @YoavL if you don't have https then the connection isn't encrypted which means an attacker tracking your traffic will see the id exposed (and I believe that's just one example)

Comment: @niceman yeah he can get the id through sniffing the traffic, but he can't do nothing with the id, he cant sqlinjection because i blocked the option. and only having an id is nothing. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @YoavL "only having an id is nothing" I believe it's "everything" :) , as Andoitz said The hacker could try different ids until they find the user they want